Aws lightsail loadbalancer Request Timout
I add the aws lightsail loadbalancer layer to my server. My server are running using ngnix setting. Some request are take longer than 3 minutes. Wihtout lightsail loadbalancer they are working well because I change the nginx setting on the server. But when i add the lightsail loadbalancer layer then these request through 504 timeout error after one minute. How can I resolve these error. Can anyone have suggesstion ?
I want response back from the server
